# Mesh is invinsible after exporting model to Substance Painter

Tags: mesh, scale

Earlier today I tried to export my model to Substance Painter, after doing that I realized that a part of my model is invisible in the program.

[image]

After searching the web for a bit I found out that negative scale can make mesh invisible, and after checking my scale I found it that it is indeed negative in that specific part of the model.

[image]

Now, the problem is that if I change the scale the whole mesh is getting messed up. Is it possible to change the scale without messing the object or fiddling with it too much afterwards?

Blend file:
[image]

**Edit**

Upon further inspection, I also noticed that from different angles some parts are visible from the back but not from the front, it looks like a normal issue but as you can see from the blend files all the faces are facing the right direction

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you tried applying the scale ? Object > Apply > Scale

Comment: Relevant - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7298/110840

Comment: You should also check Face Orientation view as part of inspecting a model.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I've checked the face Orientation and it is fine, I'll check the post you've sent and the Scale thingy in a moment

Comment: @Gorgious well it seems that Scale didn't change anything after exporting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked your model and you do have face orientation problems, the red area should be blue. In edit mode and with all selected go to Mesh > Normal > Recalculate outside.

[image]

After that, everything is fine

[image]

Comment: I just found out about it myself and was about to post an answer about it, but you were quicker ;) 

Your reward is my thanks ( and accepted answer of course )